# want to upgrade PHP 5.3 to 5.4?

Tags: php

I just started working with php so I don't have any idea what is involved with upgrades. Currently, I'm working with php 5.3, and would like to move to 5.4.  How is this done?  Is it just a simple installation of 5.4 ? Will this break code written in 5.3?

Comment: Can you tell us about your server enviroment? What OS you are running?

Answer (score 5):

[Migrating from PHP 5.3.x to PHP 5.4.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php) is the info regarding such upgrade.

Especially have a look into [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php) section. Some functions were removed in PHP 5.4 and if your PHP 5.3 code is using them, you will get errors. For example, `session_register()` function does not exist in PHP 5.4

Comment: No information is there about upgrade process only new features in 5.4 is there.

Comment: @Rhytha: How did you install PHP?

Comment: @Rhytha, the link posted shows what may break in your PHP code after upgrade. Upgrading PHP installation should not be a problem.

Comment: @bhovhannes : now got it .. show finally i have to check all upgrade and what it will effect on existing code.

Comment: @Rhyta, just download new version of PHP as zip file and unzip it into your wampp installation folder overwriting existing files. Remember to keep your php.ini file, though.

Comment: @bhovhannes: okay i will do.. after taking backup as well checking all upgrade function who will not affect my existing code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which Linux distro. you are using.

You could try:
yum update php

Or:
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi php5-cli

I highly recommend you test your code on 5.4 before upgrading any live server as mostly likely there might be some breaking differences (as normal with most PHP upgrades).